# How do I make another constructor with coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

I created Point class and Vector class in coffeescript. Both classes inherits MyObject class and constructor of both classes use super().

I want to transform Point into Vector. Therefore, I tried writing Vector.fromPoint() method. The method is used as constructor( `new Vector.fromPoint(new Point(x, y))` ).

However, I couldn't write it in coffeescript. Can it be written in coffeescript? I want to use MyObject.constructor as super() in the Vector.fromPoint constructor.

Comment: The constructor which accepts Point is another constructor. So I want to separate two constructors. fromPoint method shows clearly that it is constructor with Point. So I want fromPoint constructor.

I can't imagine how to use new in fromPoint. Which constructor does the new call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a class function, `@` is the class so why not something simple like this?

```
class Vector extends MyObject
    @fromPoint: (p) ->
        new @(p.x, p.y)
    #...
```

Or, if you don't want to allow for subclassing `Vector`:

```
class Vector extends MyObject
    @fromPoint: (p) ->
        new Vector(p.x, p.y)
    #...
```

In either case you'd say `Vector.fromPoint(some_point)` and get your `Vector` instance.

You could also replace `Vector`'s constructor so that you can `new Vector(x, y)` or `new Vector(some_point)`:

```
class Vector extends MyObject
    constructor: (args...) ->
        if(args.length == 1 && args[0] instanceof Point)
            { @x, @y } = args[0]
        else if(args.length == 2)
            [ @x, @y ] = args
        else
            # Do whatever error handling you want here...
        super()
     #...
```